# How could I eliminate names with an 'x' after them?

Tags: matlab

Hi I imported Excel data into MATLAB, it's a list of about 200 meter names with about 28 rows each.
The problem is that for each there is a duplicate for the other direction, with the same meter name with an `'x'` after it.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I can eliminate these ones with an `'x'` afterwards?
 The following is the part of my code that imports the data:
    clear all

```
fid=fopen('sue1.csv'); % Open the file sue1.csv and read it all and put it into an array
data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s','Delimiter',',','CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fid)

j = 1; k = 1; % j - turbine number, k - date number

for i = 1:length(data{1,1}) % Run through all the data
    if strcmp(data{1,1}(i),'') == 0

        meterold{j}(k,:) = data{1,1}(i,:);
%         if strcmp(data{1,1}(i),'MeterName') == 0
%             nummeter{j}(k,:) = str2num(data{1,1}(i,3:end));
%         end
        k = k + 1; 

    else
        % These commands are followed in the strings match (empty line)
        k = 1; % Reset the day counter as we're back to the beginning
        j = j + 1; % Add one to the meter counter as we're now looking at
        % a new turbine
    end
end
```

Comment: The question is confusing without the data (or atleast a sample). All I can say is why not use `csvread` if you are reading a CSV format?

Comment: Please format your code snippets correctly, that will make them much easier for us to appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer this with a sample but maybe this will help.

You can tell if a string ends in an 'x' like this:

```
if myString(end) == 'x'
```

and you can delete a row from a matrix like this:

```
M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
M(2,:) = [];
```

Hopefully you can combine these two to solve your problem.

Comment: Just a warning about deleting lines like this in a forloop, you should rahter loop from the end to the beginning otherwise you will skip checking any lines directly after a line you delete.

Comment: This would be row removal and it does work on cell matrices. Try this: M = cell(3); M(2,:) = []; Works fine on my Matlab.

Comment: I have no idea without seeing the data, but the OP wanted to delete rows conditionally. So this is one method of deleting a row.